# Record batching on bases of running total values by specific number (FileSize wise batching)

Tags: sql, sql-server

We are dealing with large recordset and are currently using NTILE() to get the range of FileIDs and then using FileID column in BETWEEN clause to get specific records set. Using FileID in BETWEEN clause is a mandatory requirement from Developers. So, we cannot have random FileIDs in one batch, it has to be incremental.

As per new requirement, we have to make range based on FileSize column, e.g. 100 GB per batch.

For example:

```
Batch 1 : 1 has 100 size So ID: 1 record only.
Batch 2 : 2,3,4,5 = 80 but it is < 100 GB, so have to take FileId 6 if 120 GB (Total 300 GB) 
Batch 3 : 7 ID has > 100 so 1 record only
And so on…
```

Below are my sample code, but it is not giving the expected result:

```
CREATE TABLE zFiles
(
    FileId   INT
   ,FileSize INT
)

INSERT INTO dbo.zFiles (
                           FileId
                          ,FileSize
                       )
VALUES (1, 100)
      ,(2, 20)
      ,(3, 20)
      ,(4, 30)
      ,(5, 10)
      ,(6, 120)
      ,(7, 400)
      ,(8, 50)
      ,(9, 100)
      ,(10, 60)
      ,(11, 40)
      ,(12, 5)
      ,(13, 20)
      ,(14, 95)
      ,(15, 40) 

DECLARE @intBatchSize FLOAT = 100;
SELECT   y.FileID ,
         y.FileSize ,
         y.RunningTotal ,
         DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY CEILING(RunningTotal / @intBatchSize)) Batch
FROM     (   SELECT i.FileID ,
                    i.FileSize ,
                    RunningTotal = SUM(i.FileSize) OVER ( ORDER BY i.FileID ) -- RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
             FROM   dbo.zFiles AS i WITH ( NOLOCK )
         ) y
ORDER BY y.FileID;
```

Result:

```
+--------+----------+--------------+-------+
| FileID | FileSize | RunningTotal | Batch |
+--------+----------+--------------+-------+
|      1 |      100 |          100 |     1 |
|      2 |       20 |          120 |     2 |
|      3 |       20 |          140 |     2 |
|      4 |       30 |          170 |     2 |
|      5 |       10 |          180 |     2 |
|      6 |      120 |          300 |     3 |
|      7 |      400 |          700 |     4 |
|      8 |       50 |          750 |     5 |
|      9 |      100 |          850 |     6 |
|     10 |       60 |          910 |     7 |
|     11 |       40 |          950 |     7 |
|     12 |        5 |          955 |     7 |
|     13 |       20 |          975 |     7 |
|     14 |       95 |         1070 |     8 |
|     15 |       40 |         1110 |     9 |
+--------+----------+--------------+-------+
```

Expected Result:

```
+--------+---------------+---------+
| FileID | FileSize (GB) | BatchNo |
+--------+---------------+---------+
|      1 |           100 |       1 |
|      2 |            20 |       2 |
|      3 |            20 |       2 |
|      4 |            30 |       2 |
|      5 |            10 |       2 |
|      6 |           120 |       2 |
|      7 |           400 |       3 |
|      8 |            50 |       4 |
|      9 |           100 |       4 |
|     10 |            60 |       5 |
|     11 |            40 |       5 |
|     12 |             5 |       6 |
|     13 |            20 |       6 |
|     14 |            95 |       6 |
|     15 |            40 |       7 |
+--------+---------------+---------+
```

We can achieve this if somehow we can reset the running total once it gets over 100. We can write a loop to have this result, but for that we need to go record by record, which is time consuming.

Please somebody help us on this?

Comment: i think your `result` shown in question is correct rather than the expected result.

Comment: @VamsiPrabhala if you examine the `result`, `Batch 2` is having total file size of 80, `Batch 5` is of 50, `Batch 8` is of 95. This all are less than 100, which is not as per the requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Small modification on above answered by Gordon Linoff and got expected result.

```html
DECLARE @intBatchSize INT = 100
;WITH cte as (
      select z.fileid, z.filesize, z.filesize as batch_filesize, 1 as batchnum
      from zfiles z
      where z.fileid = 1
      union all
      select z.fileid, z.filesize,
             (case when cte.batch_filesize  >= @intBatchSize
                   then z.filesize
                   else cte.batch_filesize + z.filesize
              end),
             (case when cte.batch_filesize  >= @intBatchSize
                   then cte.batchnum + 1
                   else cte.batchnum
              end)
      from cte join
           zfiles z
           on z.fileid = cte.fileid + 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this with a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select z.fileid, z.filesize, z.filesize as batch_filesize, 1 as batchnum
      from zfiles z
      where z.fileid = 1
      union all
      select z.fileid, z.filesize,
             (case when cte.batch_filesize + z.filesize > @intBatchSize
                   then z.filesize
                   else cte.batch_filesize + z.filesize
              end),
             (case when cte.batch_filesize + z.filesize > @intBatchSize
                   then cte.batchnum + 1
                   else cte.batchnum
              end)
      from cte join
           zfiles z
           on z.fileid = cte.fileid + 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Note:  I realize that `fileid` probably is not a sequence.  You can create a sequence using `row_number()` in a CTE, to make this work.

There is a technical reason why running sums don't work for this.  Essentially, any given fileid needs to know the breaks before it.

Comment: This puts `FileId` 6 in `BatchNo` 3, vs the expected results of `BatchNo` 2